# Grails: how to pass link in message's args

Tags: grails

In the GSP i want to pass to the `agrs` a link  in `<g:message code='myCode' args='link'>` , i tried `args="${createLink(controller:'myCon',action:'myAc')}"` but this is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be easy enough with the following in your `messages.properties` file

`my.message.key=Just a link to <a href="{0}">Something</a>`

and then calling it like this:

`<g:message code="my.message.key" args="[createLink(controller: 'foo', action: 'baz')]" />`

Keep in mind that arguments for message codes are an array, thus the brackets used above.

Comment: Thanks worked , i thought i can't write `<a href>` in the `messages.properties`